# Should I use a comma or semicolon to separate the items in this sentence

Tags: commas, lists, semicolons

> We have planned to modify the product mobile phone and address the following sustainable development goals: Responsible Consumption and Production, Good Health and Well Being.

or

> We have planned to modify the product mobile phone and address the following sustainable development goals: Responsible Consumption and Production; Good Health and Well Being.

Which one of the above is correct?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the difference between using a comma vs. using a semicolon is negligible because there are no additional commas in your list items that could cause any confusion. However, potential confusion arises from your use of "and", which can be clarified by using an Oxford comma:

> We have planned to modify the product mobile phone and address the following sustainable development goals: Responsible Consumption and Production, Good Health, and Well Being.

I assume you want to list three items here, since using a comma or semicolon to separate two items would be awkward.
If you do want to list just two items (Good Health and Well Being are one item), I would recommend the following:

> We have planned to modify the product mobile phone and address the following sustainable development goals: Responsible Consumption and Production as well as Good Health and Well Being

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am trying to separate the items 1)Responsible Consumption and Production 2) Good Health and Well Being in a single sentence

Comment: If that's the case, using "as well as" as your connector should work fine.

Comment: We have planned to modify the product mobile phone and address the sustainable development goals of Responsible Consumption and Production, and Good Health and Well Being. Is this a good replacement?